# How can I change the width of a Vue router-link?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have the following code (`IN VUE.JS`):

```html
<template>
    <router-link
        id="router-link"
     >
    </router-link>
</template>
```

```html
<script>
    ⋮
</script>
```

```html
<style scoped>
    #router-link{
        border: 2px solid black;
        width: 100px;
    }
</style>
```

**The problem:**
Even thought I set the width to 100px, the `router-link` will not change its width-size.

Can someone please help me understand why this is not working and is there a possible solution to the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, the `<router-link>` renders an `<a>`, which is normally `display:inline`, which ignores width. Add `display:inline-block` to your style to fix the issue.

```
#router-link {
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 100px;
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/n0rr0lxj6l?fontsize=14&module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue)